# Using scrapy to find specific text from multiple websites

Tags: web, web-crawler, scrapy, keyword, extract

I would like to crawl/check multiple websites(on same domain) for a specific keyword. I have found this script, but I can't find how to add the specific keyword to be search for.  What the script needs to do is find the keyword, and give the result in which link it was found. Could anyone point me to where i could read more about this ? 
I have been reading [scrapy's documentation](http://scrapy.org/doc/), but I can't seem to find this.

Thank you.

```scrapy
class FinalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "final"
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = [URL % starting_number]
def __init__(self):
    self.page_number = starting_number

def start_requests(self):
    # generate page IDs from 1000 down to 501
    for i in range (self.page_number, number_of_pages, -1):
        yield Request(url = URL % i, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    **parsing data from the webpage**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use some parser or regex to find the text you are looking for inside the response body.

every scrapy callback method contains the response body inside the `response` object, which you can check with `response.body` (for example inside the `parse` method), then you'll have to use some [`regex`](https://www.google.com.pe/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python+regex) or better `xpath` or `css` selectors to go to the path of your text knowing the xml structure of the page you crawled.

Scrapy lets you use the `response` object as a Selector, so you can go to the title of the page with `response.xpath('//head/title/text()')` for example.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Hi, the specific text is in the page, it's a number, like 100.00. I think i have gotten the Xpath, however, I can't seem to find a way to make it look for that specific text and give me the url as well at the text, so i know which url to open for that specific text ?

Comment: do you want to create a url from text? for that you only need string operations.

Comment: eLRuLL, no it's not exactly what i want. I want scrapy to visit the sites, search for that specific keyword, out of 100 websites maybe only 2 will have the  keyword i need, and if it finds that keyword, then I want it to give me back the url where it found it. Hope i got it a bit clearer now..

Comment: Ok, do you know maybe how could i limit scrapy to wait for about 10-20seconds before visiting another 500 pages for example ? The webpages itself are mostly text based, but i just don't want to be banned or anything.

Comment: you can get banned even for making 2 requests quickly, so the idea of hitting it by 500 isn't a good choice, scrapy has a way to automatically throttle the requests, you only need to set `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True` on your settings, which I think is True by default.

Comment: Ok. I can't seem to find what specific command to give to response.url ? Do you perhaps know the specific order of the code ? I suppose it's def response.url, but I can't seem to find how to make it include the url in which the text was found ?

Comment: `response` is the method argument, for example on the `parse` method, `response.url` is a string.

Comment: I don't know, depends on the page you are crawling, looks like a valid xpath

Comment: Alright, I've actually edited the xpath , so if you can just confirm if it looks alright ? And one more thing, do you know what is the limit of number of websites i can open with autothrottle enabled ? I will see now on google how can i implement what you have suggested. Thank you so much for being helpful.

Comment: I think it hits the site until seeing the site responds differently (banning statuses), then sets some delay on the retries (scrapy retries 5 times by default).

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you , again. I will write back if I'm stuck somewhere implementing this code.

Comment: Np, remember to accept the answer and upvote if it was helpful for you.