# Scrapy script , how to find specific keyword and return or print url

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

Ok, so i have to edit this completely. I have got the script partially working, i can start it without any problem, and here is the script. The paste link is here: http://pastebin.com/SKa5Wh1h and you can see what i get in the cmd line. I'm sure the keyword that is being searched is in those links, because i tried other words too, but it's not downloading them.

```
import scrapy

import requests
from scrapy.http import Request

import scrapy
from FinalSpider.items import Page  # Defined in items.py

URL = "http://url.com=%d"
starting_number = 60000
number_of_pages = 100
class FinalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "FinalSpider"
allowed_domains = ['url.com']
start_urls = [URL % starting_number]

def __init__(self):
    self.page_number = starting_number
def start_request(self):
    # generate page IDs from 1000 down to 501
    for i in range (self.page_number, number_of_pages, -1):
        yield Request(url = URL % i, callback=self.parse)


def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.xpath('//a[text()="Amount"]/@href').extract():
        yield Page(url=link)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me as to the exact issue you're experiencing. Can you provide some more concrete details?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to combine some scripts that I'm finding on the internet to do the following task. Go to the website, find the specific keyword, which is for example "100", then just print out/save the url where it was found. I've tried to combine those scripts from the net to do this, but i keep failing because I do not understand the language. So, I posted here to see if somebody can direct me or knows the code that can do this. I'm just getting frustrated doing this since 4 days ago,and I have only gotten through maybe 50% of the project I'm working on. So I decided to seek help here.

Comment: @user5616520, If you want to get used to extract data from a webpage in scrapy, use the [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html), there you can interactively play Selectors and XPaths. I highly recommend you to also install [Ipython](http://ipython.org/install.html) to have a more friendly experience.

Comment: Hi, memoselyk. I  will install lpython and poke around it But I don't need to extract any data per se. What i need is to just find the specific keyword and extract the url where it was found, because i have to check the urls manually. Yes, this is data extraction, but it's a lot more simple, I believe, than extracting different type of data. However, so far I don't know how to implement these two tasks in my code ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using scrapy to find specific text from multiple websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989925/using-scrapy-to-find-specific-text-from-multiple-websites)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are asking two things,

1. How to extract some element?

The *xpath* that you are providing, `response.xpath('//100.00()')`, is an invalid xpath expressions.

If you want to find an `a` tag with some subtring in the text, like `<a href="something"> 100.00 </a>`, the correct xpath would be `'//a[contains(text(), "100.00")]'`. Note the use of `contains`, if you have the *exact* text you could use `'//a[text() == "100.00"]'`.

2. What do you with the found element?

In Scrapy, it's customary to create an `Item` class that would hold the data you have scrapped, logically structured by the `Field`s you have defined.

So first, you create a `Item` subclass, with a `url` `Field`, and in your spider, `return` or `yield` a new instance of that `Item` with the field `url` set to the value you found in the page.

Putting all this together,

You have to create an `Item`, as shown [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#declaring-items):

```
import scrapy

class Page(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

Then, in your spider extract all the meaningful data from the `response` object. Look at the examples [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) to get a feeling. But in general your code will be like,

```
import scrapy
from myproject.items import Page  # Defined in items.py

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    [...]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//a[text()="100.00"]/@href').extract():
            yield Page(url=link)
```

Comment: Hi. I have the exact text i need to be found. It's 100.00, so i need to use what you suggested " //a[text() == "100.00"]" ? But, what I don't understand is do i implement this in the main script,and how, or do i have to put this in the items.py script as well ?  And 2, I would like the found element to be saved in the form of urls. So for example out of 500 urls, if it finds the text in 10 urls to save those 10 urls. Is this too much work or even possible or it just seems to me complicated  because I just started learning all this.

Comment: @user5616520, I've added some sample code trying to provide you general guidelines. If you get stuck in the parsing, use the scrapy shell until you got working code that you can simply copy to the `parse` method.

Comment: This is the error msg i get @memoselyk,   http://pastebin.com/KsWKEjsB I can't paste it here, so can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ? I know that the module myproject.items doesn't exist. So this should be items.py , if i'm not mistaken . Actually , i don't think it should, because items is different.

Comment: Ok, so I finally managed, I think, to get this working. Well, at least i can start it without any errors, but this is what i get now. It doesn't crawl any page. Here is paste bin link http://pastebin.com/SKa5Wh1h